# Xamarin Drop overlay filters

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio, xamarin.mac

I have to create Drop Overlay filters, as in the image below, The drop overlay should appear on click of the filter icon in the toolbar.

[image]

For now i am using the following code, Which do now serve the purpose as per the requirement.

```
private void FilterEvent()
        {
      await DisplayActionSheet("", "", null, "Filter 1", "Filter 2", "Filter 3");
        }
```

Can any once help me to create the filters as in the attached image.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion to achieve this is to by using an AbsoluteLayout, and place the **filter list** above the image (Intially give **IsVisible = false**). when you Tap on the filter button, give **IsVisible = true** and Use animation [LayoutTo](http://iosapi.xamarin.com/index.aspx?link=M%3AXamarin.Forms.ViewExtensions.LayoutTo(Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement%2CXamarin.Forms.Rectangle%2CSystem.UInt32%2CXamarin.Forms.Easing)) it would visualize it as drop down.

Comment: I have listview in the screen, I want filter overlay independent of screen content, Could you please suggest sample code.